# Is it an overhead to use @Builder(toBuilder = true) instead of setters?

Tags: java, performance, immutability, setter, builder

I always strive to make my code fully immutable and not utilize setters at all.

When I need to update an object, dto or entity I use `@Builder(toBuilder = true)` instead of setters.

```
public Car updateCar(final String id) {
    final Car existing = carRepository.getById(id);
    final Car.CarBuilder builder = existing.toBuilder().make("Mercedes-Benz");
    if (anyCondition) {
        builder.status("READY");
    }
    final Car updatedCar = builder.build();
    return carRepository.save(updatedCar);
}
```

I would like to ask you is it really bad from a performance perspective that instead of setting a value into an already instantiated object, I create a new one?

Maybe in the above piece of code, it's not significant but I also may require to change one field in all objects in a collection thus the space complexity would be linear.

What approach do you prefer: setters or toBuilder?

P.S.: the code snippet above is just for better understanding of how I utilize `toBuilder`

Comment: It looks like you're forgetting to check if the returned value is valid (and then returning early). You use the builder pattern primarily to cut down a complex object's construction, the performance overhead (if non-negligible somehow) would be in making new objects.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking about is it very significant performance overhead in making new objects or I can sacrifice it to ensure immutability?

Comment: Well now you're talking two slightly separate problems; immutability and object creation. The first enables you to keep a permanent cache of relevant objects, which is good for data with high usage, and either a small set of possible objects or a high likelihood of duplicate objects (e.g. String is immutable). The second has to do with _how_ you allocate those objects. The builder pattern in itself should not cause an overhead, but this caching approach you're attempting would (almost) solve an issue with objects which were _arbitrarily_ expensive to create

Comment: @Pavel Do you need other clarifications?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to ask you is it really bad from a performance
>   perspective that instead of setting a value into an already
>   instantiated object, I create a new one?

You're asking us, and yourself, the wrong question.
You shouldn't really be concerned about *performance* for such simple, data-carrier, classes.
Benchmark (see [JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html)) and see.

But from a purely theoretical standpoint, the only overhead is the creation of another object (which size in memory depends on its members' layout), the additional step of *transferring* the primitive values/references from the builder instance to the resulting instance (maybe also more work for the GC? I wouldn't even consider that).
Thus some more CPU cycles.

Look also at [Immutables](https://github.com/immutables/immutables), look at how many people and companies are using it, and ask yourself if for your simple usecases you should really consider asking this question.

---

Take this class

```
public class Car {
    private String maker;
    private int year;
    private int kms;

    // Getter - setters
}
```

The size is approximately `16 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 28` bytes.
Now, using a builder such as

```
public class CarBuilder {
    private String maker;
    private int year;
    private int kms;

    public CarBuilder setMaker(final String maker) {
        this.maker = maker;
        return this;
    }

    public CarBuilder setYear(final int year) {
        this.year = year;
        return this;
    }

    public CarBuilder setKms(final int kms) {
        this.kms = kms;
        return this;
    }

    public Car createCar() {
        return new Car(maker, year, kms);
    }
}
```

The size is still approximately `16 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 28` bytes.

That means you'll have at least **doubled** the bytes used in the heap for **just the class** using a builder.
However, what you need to think about is Java being **reference-based**. That means all the created objects' *pointers* will simply be copied to the produced `Car` instance. The objects will still be unique in memory.

---

After your edit, maybe what you're trying to do is *Object Pooling*?
In that case, consider [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/).

Comment: Also worth noting that it seems like there are two database operations happening in the method. Unless we're talking about an in-memory database, the time spent in these two calls will outweigh (by several orders of magnitude) any overhead from copying fields of a bean.

Comment: @biziclop absolutely! Short lived objects are *never* a weight (well, that also depends on the GC) for the JVM.